# FastAPI Class based Design

Tags: python, spring, fastapi

I am new to the `FastApi` world. Can somebody review my below `Fast API` design? It is working but doesn't follow `FastApi` conventions. I find it much cleaner and follows layered architecture taking inspiration from `Java` `Spring-boot` landscape. What are pros and cons of this desing.

`routes -> services -> crud -> models` and using `schemas`.

Can like `Springboot` I can have something like `@Autowired`

**plant_model.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text
from app.database.postgres import Base

class Plant(Base):
    __tablename__ = "plant"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    type = Column(String)
    description = Column(Text)
```

**plant_schemas.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class PlantBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: str

class PlantCreate(PlantBase):
    pass

class PlantInDB(PlantBase):
    id: int

class PlantPublic(PlantInDB):
    pass
```

**plant_crud.py**

```
from typing import List
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from app.database.postgres import SessionLocal
from .plant_schemas import PlantCreate, PlantInDB
from .plant_models import Plant


class PlantCrud:

    def __init__(self, db: Session = SessionLocal()) -> None:
        self.db = db

    def create_plant(self, plantCreate: PlantCreate):
        db_plant = Plant(plantCreate.model_dump())
        self.db.add(db_plant)
        self.db.commit()    
        return db_plant

    def get_plants(self, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
        return self.db.query(Plant).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

**plant_service.py**

```
from fastapi import Depends
from app.api.plant.plant_crud import PlantCrud
from app.api.plant.plant_schemas import PlantCreate

class PlantService:

    def __init__(self, plantCrud: PlantCrud = PlantCrud()) -> None:
        self.plantCrud = plantCrud

    def create_plant(self, plantCreate: PlantCreate):
        return self.plantCrud.create_plant(plantCreate)

    def get_plants(self, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
        return self.plantCrud.get_plants(skip, limit)
```

**plant_routes.py**

```
from app.api.plant.plant_models import Plant
from app.api.plant.plant_schemas import PlantCreate, PlantInDB
from app.api.plant.plant_service import PlantService
from fastapi import Depends, APIRouter, HTTPException
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends

router = APIRouter()

class PlantRoutes:

    def __init__(self, plantService: PlantService = PlantService()) -> None:
        self.plant_service = plantService

    def get_plants(self):
        return self.plant_service.get_plants()
    
    def create_plant(self, plantCreate: PlantCreate):
        return self.plant_service.create_plant(plantCreate)


plantRoutes = PlantRoutes()
router.add_api_route("/plants", plantRoutes.get_plants, methods=["GET"], response_model=list[PlantInDB])
router.add_api_route("/plants", plantRoutes.create_plant, methods=["POST"], response_model=PlantInDB, status_code=201)
```

**main.py**

````
# app/__init__.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
import sys
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

current_script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Add the parent directory (project directory) to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(current_script_dir))


my_app = FastAPI()
origins = [
   "*"
]
my_app.add_middleware(
   CORSMiddleware,
   allow_origins=origins,
   allow_credentials=True,
   allow_methods=["*"],
   allow_headers=["*"],
)

from app.api.plant.plant_routes import router as plant_router
my_app.include_router(plant_router, prefix="/plant", tags=["plant"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    from main import my_app
    uvicorn.run("main:my_app", host="127.0.0.1", reload=True)
```
````

Comment: Since you are using `SQLAlchemy` and `Pydantic` as part of your study you should checkout [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/)

Answer (score 3):

## missing docstring

These are obvious and lovely:

```
class PlantBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: str

class PlantInDB(PlantBase):
    id: int
```

These are obscure:

```
class PlantCreate(PlantBase):
    pass

class PlantPublic(PlantInDB):
    pass
```

Clearly you intend they should be different in some way.
But you neglected to tell us about the difference.
Use a docstring for that.

The `PlantService` class appears to be all boilerplate.
Please give it a docstring which explains why we need it,
and how it differs from `PlantCrud`.

## appropriate name

I read these two verbs and couldn't believe my eyes.

```
    def create_plant( ... ):
        ...
        self.db.add(db_plant)
        self.db.commit()
```

Then I came back to this:

```
    def __init__(self, db: Session = SessionLocal()) -> None:
        self.db = db
```

OIC, it is not a DB at all, it is a session.
So call it a session, or perhaps `self.sess`.

And it's still not clear to me what distinct role `PlantCreate` plays.

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell the parameter `plant_create`
instead of `plantCreate`.
Similarly for `plant_crud`.

## mutable default parameter

Evaluating an expression just once, at `import` time,
rather than N times for N invocations,
can be surprising behavior for the unsuspecting maintenance engineer.

```
    def __init__(self, db: Session = SessionLocal()) -> None:
```

Prefer this common idiom.

```
    def __init__(self, db: Session = None)) -> None:
        self.db = db or SessionLocal()
```

## fix PYTHONPATH

```
# Add the parent directory (project directory) to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(current_script_dir))
```

No, please don't do that.
Arrange for `sys.path` to be configured properly from the get go,
during initial interpreter startup.
Set the env var prior to invocation,
perhaps using a `make` target or
perhaps using a shebang like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=../..:/some/where python
```

Also, please keep all your `main.py` imports together at top of file.
The `__main__` guard is nice enough, but it's not
like anyone will be doing `import main`, there's simply
no app code to test.
A unit test might go faster by
avoiding an expensive `import uvicorn`,
but for *this* code there won't be any such tests.